# Django Regex matching long url

Tags: python, regex, django

I have this long url and I want to match the string after `?` and have it available in self.kwargs of Class Based View.

new_timer/?UID=046F1572564080&runtime=1102&seconds=30stillrunning=1&numstoredtimes=3&storedtimes=13:2-23:32-48:43&checksum=71

I tried the following and it's not working.

```
Urlpatterns = [
    # bunch of awesome urls
    url(r'^new_timer/(?P<params>[^/]+)/$',NewTimerView.as_view(),
        name='new_timer'),
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "The URLconf searches against the requested URL, as a normal Python string. This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain name." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Two mistakes in your regex: `^new_timer/(?P<params>[^/]+)/$`

1. You are not matching `?` at all. Also you will have to `escape` it.
2. You have `/` in end. Whereas there is no `/` in URL at end.

Correct regex should be: `^new_timer/\?(?P<params>[^/]+)$`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AmNAsX/1/)**